# Convert list of string to list VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a string in Vue JS like

```
'[{"Request" : {"data":"1,2,3"}}, {"Request" : {"data":"a,b,c"}}]'
```

I want to have a list with values both with a dict each
something like

```
[{"Request" : {"data":"1,2,3"}}, {"Request" : {"data":"a,b,c"}}]
```

Basically want to convert string list to actual list

Comment: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: Hello, JSON.parse() convert json string to json not list. if you see the string its a list and or list of json in string form. trying to convert that

Comment: the list is JSON JSON only

Comment: Isnt it a string of list, it starts and ends with '[ ]' so we cant convert to json ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `JSON.parse` to convert `string` to `JSON`

```js
input = '[{"Request" : {"data":"1,2,3"}}, {"Request" : {"data":"a,b,c"}}]'

console.log(JSON.parse(input));
```